Is is true that $\lim E[Z_n| F_n] = E[Z|F_{\infty}] $, where $Z_n \rightarrow Z$ a.s., $(Z_n)$ bounded and $F_\infty =\cap_{n\geq1}F_n$
Let  $(Z_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of bounded random variables converging a.s. to some $Z$. Let $(\mathcal F_n)_{n \geq 1 }$ be a sequence of decreasing filtration and let $\mathcal F_\infty = \cap_{n\geq 1} \mathcal F_n$. Is it true that
$$ \lim E[Z_n|\mathcal F_n] = E[Z|F_{\infty}] \quad a.s.?$$
I know there is a lemma like this when $(\mathcal F_n)_{n \geq 1 } $ is increasing but not sure if this is true. If this is a duplicate, please let me know (I tried to search for this result but couldn't find anything on this site). Thank you in advance!

The lemma in question is Hunt's lemma. Assume, in addition to the a.s. convergence of $Z_n$ to $Z$, that there is an integrable r.v. $X$ such that $|Z_n|\le X$. Then $\Bbb E[Z_n\mid\mathcal F_n]\to\Bbb E[Z\mid \mathcal F_\infty]$ a.s.
Indeed, you have $|Z_n-Z|\le 2|X|$, so $X_N:=\sup_{n\ge N}|Z_n-Z|$ converges a.s. to $0$ and is dominated by the integrable r.v. $2|X|$; therefore $X_N\to 0$ in $L^1$.
Now for $n\ge N$,
$$
\eqalign{
\Big|\Bbb E[Z_n\mid\mathcal F_n]-\Bbb E[Z\mid\mathcal F_\infty]\Big|
&\le \Big|\Bbb E[Z_n\mid\mathcal F_n]-\Bbb E[Z\mid\mathcal F_n]\Big|+\Big|\Bbb E[Z \mid\mathcal F_n]-\Bbb E[Z\mid\mathcal F_\infty]\Big|\cr
&\le \Bbb E[|Z_n -Z|\mid F_n]+\Big|\Bbb E[Z \mid\mathcal F_n]-\Bbb E[Z\mid\mathcal F_\infty]\Big|\cr
&\le \Bbb E[X_N\mid F_n]+\Big|\Bbb E[Z \mid\mathcal F_n]-\Bbb E[Z\mid\mathcal F_\infty]\Big|\cr
}
$$
The term
$$
\Big|\Bbb E[Z \mid\mathcal F_n]-\Bbb E[Z\mid\mathcal F_\infty]\Big|
$$
converges to $0$ a.s as $n\to\infty$, by the backward martingale convergence theorem. By the same theorem
$$
\Bbb E[X_N\mid \mathcal F_n]\to \Bbb E[X_N\mid\mathcal F_\infty]
$$
as $n\to\infty$, for each $N$. Thus, for each $N$,
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\Big|\Bbb E[Z_n\mid\mathcal F_n]-\Bbb E[Z\mid\mathcal F_\infty]\Big|\le \Bbb E[X_N\mid\mathcal F_\infty],\qquad\hbox{a.s.}
$$
This final upper bound converges to $0$ (in $L^1$) as $n\to \infty$ because  $X_N\to 0$ in $L^1$.

This is great! I tried to used limsup as well but didn't see the trick fixing the big $N$ at first and let $N$ go to $\infty$ later, +1 for your nice proof. Do you happen to know a counter-example when there is no $X$ dominating $Z_n$?
